# Dynamic output path for partitioned parquet files in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet, mapr

We're using MapR FS with rolling volumes and there's a necessity to align partitioned output parquet files with corresponding volumes.

```
df
 .write
 .partitionBy("year", "month", "day", "hour")
 .parquet("/data/nfs/{year}/{month}/{day}/datastore")
```

The idea was to resolve paths at runtime via custom output committer:

```
class MaprParquetOutputComitter(outputPath: Path, context: TaskAttemptContext)
  extends ParquetOutputCommitter(
    MaprParquetOutputComitter.resolvePath(outputPath), 
    context)

object MaprParquetOutputComitter extends StrictLogging {
  def resolvePath(p: Path): Path = {
    logger.info(p.toString)

    // Retrieve year, month and day from path object
    // and replace placeholders with extracted values

    new Path(resolvedPath)
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, it appears that `outputPath` looks like this `"/data/nfs/{year}/{month}/{day}/datastore"`, but not like `"/data/nfs/{year}/{month}/{day}/datastore/year=2018/month=6/day=25/hour=8"`.

Is there any way to get output path that has partition piece in it with this approach (overriding `ParquetOutputCommitter`)? Or, maybe, there's another solution to achieve this goal?

Comment: Does your `DataFrame` have respective `year`, `month`, `day` and `hour` columns?

Comment: @botchniaque, yep.